# Pandas - Splitting data from one column into multiple columns

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe in the below format:

```
id, data
101, [{"tree":[
               {"Group":"1001","sub-group":3,"Child":"100267","Child_1":"8 cm"},
               {"Group":"1002","sub-group":1,"Child":"102280","Child_1":"4 cm"},
               {"Group":"1003","sub-group":0,"Child":"102579","Child_1":"0.1 cm"}]}]
102, [{"tree":[
               {"Group":"2001","sub-group":3,"Child":"200267","Child_1":"6 cm"},
               {"Group":"2002","sub-group":1,"Child":"202280","Child_1":"4 cm"}]}]
103,
```

I am trying to have data from this one column split into multiple columns

Expected output:

```
id, Group, sub-group, Child, Child_1, Group, sub-group, Child, Child_1, Group, sub-group, Child, Child_1
101, 1001, 3, 100267, 8 cm, 1002, 1, 102280, 4 cm, 1003, 0, 102579, 0.1 cm
102, 2001, 3, 200267, 6 cm, 2002, 1, 2022280, 4 cm
103
```

Output of `df.loc[:15, ['id','data']].to_dict()`

```
{'id': {1: '101',
        4: '102',
        11: '103',
        15: '104',
        16: '105'},
        'data': {1: '[{"tree":[{"Group":"","sub-group":"3","Child":"100267","Child_1":"8 cm"}]}]',
        4: '[{"tree":[{"sub-group":"0.01","Child_1":"4 cm"}]}]',
        11: '[{"tree":[{"sub-group":null,"Child_1":null}]}]',
        15: '[{"tree":[{"Group":"1003","sub-group":15,"Child":"child_","Child_1":"41 cm"}]}]',
        16: '[{"tree":[{"sub-group":"0.00","Child_1":"0"}]}]'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `explode` on the column data, create a dataframe from it, add a cumcount column, then some shape change with `set_index`, `stack`, `unstack` and `drop` to fit your expected output, `join` back to the column id

```
s = df['data'].dropna().str['tree'].explode()
df_f = df[['id']].join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), s.index)\
                         .assign(cc=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1)\
                         .set_index('cc', append=True)\
                         .stack()\
                         .unstack(level=[-2,-1])\
                         .droplevel(0, axis=1), 
                       how='left')
print (df_f)
    id Group sub-group   Child Child_1 Group sub-group   Child Child_1 Group  \
0  101  1001         3  100267    8 cm  1002         1  102280    4 cm  1003   
1  102  2001         3  200267    6 cm  2002         1  202280    4 cm   NaN   
2  103   NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN   

  sub-group   Child Child_1  
0         0  102579  0.1 cm  
1       NaN     NaN     NaN  
2       NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Note: while it does fit your expected output, having several times the same column name is not really a good practice. I would rather remove the method `drop` and flatten the multiindex column.

Edit: After some comments, I guess one way to actually go through the whole column with some weird format:

```
import ast
def f(x):
    try: 
        return ast.literal_eval(x.replace('null', "'nan'"))[0]['tree'] 
    except:
        return [{}]
# then create s with 
s = df['data'].apply(f).explode()
# then create df_f like above
```

Comment: nice one, I couldn't get the indices to align in mine

Comment: @Ben.T thanks for the reply. I however just get the id column returned back when I try the above code.. using pandas version 1.0.1

Comment: @Ben.T `type(df['data'].iloc[0])` returns  `str`

Comment: @Ben.T, after importing `ast` module, it gave me this message `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x12208b8d0>`. Have edited my post with the output of `df.loc[:3, ['id','data']].to_dict()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213258/discussion-between-kevin-nash-and-ben-t).

Comment: @Ben.T unfortunately first code gives a `KeyError: 0` message while the second gives `IndexError: list index out of range` error :(

Comment: @Ben.T it was a dump that was shared to me to split the data across columns..

Comment: @KevinNash see my edit to create `s`, without all the data and seeing all the exception possible in the format, it is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: @Ben.T thanks for all the help. I will take a look at the data source..